# notifyDataSetChanged() does not update the listview

Tags: android

I have a list of 4 items, I have used listview. I want to change a string dynamically on recieving internal event. I see that when I receive the event I am setting the string correctly but and then calling

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but the list is not getting updated.

Comment: Please provide more source code for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same experience. The cause was that the list adapter was updating on the wrong thread i.e. not the UI thread. This is easily solved by changing the adapter data on the UI thread through (as I found on other posts):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         // code that changes the list adapter data
     }
});
```

Of course you can always create a (inner) class that implements Runnable that is provided with the list adapter and data to add, insert etc.

Note: calling notifyDataSetInvalidated() or notifyDataSetChanged() will not be necessary as it is called by default, unless you turned it off explicitly with setNotifyOnChange(false);

Answer (score 0):

I think that notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the add (or insert), remove or clear functions on adapter.
You can rebuilt the list adapter for force to refresh the listView.

Excuse me for my bad english